# Pass -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow to jvm in jnlp file

Tags: java, jvm, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm missing a stack trace in my log file and I believe it is due to the stack trace being optimized away be the JVM (see [NullPointerException in Java with no StackTrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411487/nullpointerexception-in-java-with-no-stacktrace))

I have tried to pass in `-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` via my jnlp file like this:

```
...java-vm-args="-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow"...
```

but it has no effect. And it looks like setting `-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` (see [JNLP File Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html)) via java-vm-args is not supported.

Is there another way of stopping the JVM from omitting stack traces?

--- Edit:

I added `-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` via

```
Control Panel > Java > Java (tab) > View (button) > Runtime parameters (field)
```

as (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668723/remote-debugging-java-web-start-under-jvm-1-8)) that worked fine.

Comment: I don't remember if this is an option that can be changed while the VM is running but it may be worth a try.

Comment: No, `OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` cannot be changed in run-time. Try setting `-client` or `-Xint` JVM argument to disable server compiler. The application will run slower, but it won't skip stacktraces.